# Plugin with specific admin menu icon

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

My new plugin uses the **default icon** set of WP in the **admin-menu**. That is not what I want.

How do I code within my **plugin** or via **functions.php** a specific admin menu icon that suites my needs for my plugin?

> Is there a tiny code script / example to use where I can define what icon/image I want?

Also do not want to use an external plugin for this. It has to be a part of my plugin.

Hope some of you can give me a good start with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **custom menu** you can use:

```
<?php 

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); 

?>
```

Second last option is for the **custom icon url**

Here is the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) from wordpress.org, you can read more about wordpress administration menu.

Comment: Also the hint. The `$icon_url` accepted also a Dashicon name. It is much more easier and solid for usage on different devices. You find helpful tools in the plugin https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style or on the [Dashicon Site](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#images-alt).